# Printing Hash of Hash into a Matrix Table in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a data structure like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $hash = {
             'abTcells' => {
                             'mesenteric_lymph_node' => {
                                                         'Itm2a'   => '664.661',
                                                         'Gm16452' => '18.1425',
                                                         'Sergef'  => '142.8205'
                                                       },

                               'spleen'       =>   {  
                                                       'Itm2a' => '58.07155',
                                                       'Dhx9' => '815.2795',
                                                       'Ssu72' => '292.889'

                                                }
                            }
            };
```

What I want to do is to print it out into this format:

```
                mesenteric_lymph_node       spleen
Itm2a               664.661                 58.07155
Gm16452             18.1425                 NA
Sergef              142.8205                NA
Dhx9                 NA                     815.2795
Ssu72                NA                     292.889
```

What's the way to do it.

I'm currently stuck with the following code https://eval.in/44207

```
foreach my $ct (keys %{$hash}) {
     print "$ct\n\n";
     my %hash2 = %{$hash->{$ct}};
       foreach my $ts (keys %hash2) {
       print "$ts\n";
       my %hash3 = %{$hash2{$ts}};
       foreach my $gn (keys %hash3) {
          print "$gn $hash3{$gn}\n";
       }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Text::Table](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3aTable) for output. [Beautify to taste](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SHLOMIF/Text-Table-1.127/examples/Text-Table-UTF8-example.pl).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Table;

my $hash = {
    'abTcells' => {
        'mesenteric_lymph_node' => {
            'Itm2a'   => '664.661',
            'Gm16452' => '18.1425',
            'Sergef'  => '142.8205'
        },
        'spleen' =>  {
            'Itm2a' => '58.07155',
            'Dhx9' => '815.2795',
            'Ssu72' => '292.889'
        }
    }
};

my $struct = $hash->{abTcells};

my @cols = sort keys %{ $struct };
my @rows = sort keys %{ { map {
    my $x = $_;
    map { $_ => undef }
    keys %{ $struct->{$x} }
} @cols } };

my $tb = Text::Table->new('', @cols);

for my $r (@rows) {
    $tb->add($r, map $struct->{$_}{$r} // 'NA', @cols);
}

print $tb;
```

Output:

```
        mesenteric_lymph_node spleen
Dhx9    NA                    815.2795
Gm16452  18.1425              NA
Itm2a   664.661                58.07155
Sergef  142.8205              NA
Ssu72   NA                    292.889
```

Now, the order of the rows above is different than the one you show because I wanted it to be consistent. If you know the set of all possible rows, then you can specify another order obviously.

Answer (score 1):

First thing would be to separate out the two hashes:

```
my %lymph_node =  %{ $hash->{abTcells}->{mesenteric_lymph_node} };
my %spleen     =  %{ $hash->{abTcells}->{spleen} };
```

Now, you have two separate hashes that contains the data you want.

What we need is a list of all the keys. Let's make a third hash that contains your keys.

```
my %keys;
map { $keys{$_} = 1; } keys %lymph_node, keys %spleen;
```

Now, we can go through all your keys and print the value for each of the two hashes. If one of the hashes doesn't have the data, we'll set it to `NA`:

```
for my $value ( sort keys %keys ) {
    my $spleen_value;
    my $lymph_nodes_value;
    $spleen_value = exists $spleen{$value} ? $spleen{$value} : "NA";
    $lymph_node_value = exists $lymph_node{$value} ? $lymph_node{$value} : "NA";
    printf "%-20.20s  %-9.5f %-9.5f\n", $key, $lymph_node_value, $spleen_value;
}
```

The `printf` statement is a nice way to tabularize data. You'll have to create the headings yourself. The `... ? ... : ...` statement is an abbreviated `if/then/else` If the statement before the `?` is true, then the value is the value between the `?` and the `:`. Else, the value is the value after the `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your inner hashes have the same keys, So do a foreach on one of the hashes to get the key, and then print both.